# Dividing multiple overlapping sets into non overlapping sets

Tags: c#, algorithm, set

I have multiple sets which have overlapping elements.

```
e1, e2, e3, e4
e7,e9,e10
e1,e4
e2,e7
e3,e9
e10,e11,e12
e11,e12
```

I want to divide the above sets such that they do not overlap and also follow the existing boundaries in the blocks. So output I am expecting is

```
e1, e4
e2
e3
e7
e9
e10
e11, e12
```

What algo/function can I write to do this?

Comment: What is the logic behind those results?

Comment: largest number of elements in current set which occur together in all sets.

Comment: essentially disjoint sets from a collection of overlapping sets

Comment: how does e1, e4 not overlap with e2?

Comment: e1, e4 and e2 are individual elements. How can elements overlap? Sets overlap e.g. 1st and 4th set overlap on e2

Comment: What are the exact constraints and optimization objective?

Comment: minimum number of disjoint sets from the collection of sets

Comment: I still don't get it, could you write it out mathematically?

Answer (score 2):

I would start by calculating a "participation signature" for each element. For example the element e1 participates in the sets 1 and 3, so its signature should be 1010000. Elements with the same signature should be positioned in the same final set.

---

**Update:** Here is an implementation of this idea, using the [`BigInteger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger) class as participation signature.

```
using System.Numerics;

public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetDistinctGroupedByOrigin<T>(
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> source)
{
    return source
        .SelectMany((s, i) => s.Select(e => (Element: e, Index: i)))
        .GroupBy(e => e.Element)
        .Select(g => (Element: g.Key, Signature: g.Aggregate(
            BigInteger.Zero, (acc, e) => acc | (BigInteger.One << e.Index))))
        .GroupBy(e => e.Signature, e => e.Element);
}
```

Usage example:

```
var source = new string[][]
{
    new string[] { "e1", "e2", "e3", "e4" },
    new string[] { "e7", "e9", "e10" },
    new string[] { "e1", "e4" },
    new string[] { "e2", "e7" },
    new string[] { "e3", "e9" },
    new string[] { "e10", "e11", "e12" },
    new string[] { "e11", "e12" },
};
foreach (var set in GetDistinctGroupedByOrigin(source))
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", set));
}
```

Output:

> e1, e4
>   e2
>   e3
>   e7
>   e9
>   e10
>   e11, e12